# Error in installing mysql-python due to link.exe

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

The command

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\us ers\\qasim\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-rfd9z8\\mysql-python\\setup.py';exec (compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),  __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\qasim\appdata\local\temp\pip-hgqr iy-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"
```

Failed with error code 1 in c:\users\qasim\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-rfd9z8\mysql -python

Comment: you may try easy_install "easy_install MySQL-python"

Comment: to install http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-install-easy_install/